# draw globe with flight paths

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a....unique problem. I'm making a game where I will dynamically draw points(representing cities) with flight paths between them. The user will then select these cities and perform further actions.

Also, the globe has to be able to rotate about one axis, so the user can easily see all the cities.

I've figured out a way to draw points and paths on the sphere. The points are tiny spheres, and the paths are bezier curves I've generated. I;ve enclosed them within a glpushmatrix() and glpopmatrix() along with a glrotate() call in the beginning so that all things(the globe, paths and vertices) rotate in unison

The only problem I'm facing is to figure out which vertex the user has clicked. glrotate modifies the model matrix, so do I have to calculate the new positions of the vertices at every rotation? I'm using glunproject to figure out where the user has clicked. 
OR, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Here's my code:-

```
float venusRotate;
vector<vector3f>cityVertices;

//bezier curve
GLfloat bezierCurve(float t, GLfloat P0,
                    GLfloat P1, GLfloat P2) {
    // Cubic bezier Curve
    GLfloat point = pow(t,2)*P0 + 2*P1*t*(1-t) + P2*pow(1-t, 2);
    return point;
}


vector3f randomSpherePoint()
{
    float u = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
    float v = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
    float theta = 2 * M_PI * u;
    float phi = acos(2*v-1);
    float x=(10*sin(phi)*cos(theta));
    float y=(10 * sin(phi) * sin(theta));
    float z=10*cos(phi);
    return vector3f(x, y, z);
}


void drawRandomSpherePoints()
{
    for (int i=0; i<400; i++)
    {
        glPushMatrix();

        vector3f point=cityVertices.at(i);
        glTranslatef(point.x, point.y, point.z);
        glutSolidSphere(0.25, 10, 10);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

}
vector3f GetOGLPos(int x, int y)
{
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
    GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

    glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
    glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

    winX = (float)x;
    winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)y;
    glReadPixels( x, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );

    gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
    return vector3f(posX, posY, posZ);
}

void mouseClick(int button,int state,int x, int y)
{
    vector3f Coord=GetOGLPos(x, y);
    cout<<Coord.x<<" "<<Coord.y<<" "<<Coord.z<<endl;
//    for (int i=0;i<cityVertices.size();i++)
//    {
//        if (Coord.x-cityVertices.at(i).x<CLICK_ACCURACY && Coord.z-cityVertices.at(i).z<CLICK_ACCURACY && Coord.z-cityVertices.at(i).z<CLICK_ACCURACY  ) {
//        }
//    }
}



void preProcessEvents()
{
    CURRENT_TIME=(float)glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    DELTA_TIME=CURRENT_TIME-LAST_TIME;
    LAST_TIME=CURRENT_TIME;


    mouse::update();
    //mouse processing
    Camera::rotationAngles.y+=(float)mouse::deltaX*MOUSE_SENSITIVITY;
    Camera::rotationAngles.x-=(float)mouse::deltaY*MOUSE_SENSITIVITY;

    if (Camera::rotationAngles.x>MAX_TILT)
    {
        Camera::rotationAngles.x=MAX_TILT;
    }
    else if (Camera::rotationAngles.x<-1*MAX_TILT)
    {
        Camera::rotationAngles.x=-1*MAX_TILT;
    }
    if (keyBoard::key['w'])
    {
        Camera::position.z-=WALKING_SPEED*DELTA_TIME*Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.y);
        Camera::position.x-=WALKING_SPEED*DELTA_TIME*Math::cosd(Camera::rotationAngles.y);
    }
    else if (keyBoard::key['s'])
    {
        Camera::position.z+=WALKING_SPEED*DELTA_TIME*Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.y);
        Camera::position.x+=WALKING_SPEED*DELTA_TIME*Math::cosd(Camera::rotationAngles.y);
    }
    else if (keyBoard::key['a'])
    {
        Camera::rotationAngles.y-=WALKING_SPEED*DELTA_TIME*3;
    }
    else if (keyBoard::key['d'])
    {
        Camera::rotationAngles.y+=WALKING_SPEED*DELTA_TIME*3;
    }
    else if (keyBoard::key['f'])
    {
        venusRotate++;
    }
    else if (keyBoard::key[' '])
    {
        glutDestroyWindow(subWindow);
    }

}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    float aspectRatio;
    if (h==0)
    {
        h=1;
    }
    aspectRatio=float(w)/float(h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w ,h);
    gluPerspective(45, aspectRatio, 0.01, 100000000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}


void display()
{
    preProcessEvents();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(Camera::position.x, Camera::position.y, Camera::position.z,
              Camera::position.x+Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.x)*Math::cosd(Camera::rotationAngles.y),
              Camera::position.y+Math::cosd(Camera::rotationAngles.x),
              Camera::position.z+Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.x)*Math::sind(Camera::rotationAngles.y),
              0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(-1, 0,-3);
    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 2.0f,-3);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 0.0f,-3);
    glEnd();





    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->textureID);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(100, 100);
    glVertex3f(100,0,100);

    glTexCoord2f(-100, 100);
    glVertex3f(-100,0,100);

    glTexCoord2f(-100,-100);
    glVertex3f(-100,0,-100);

    glTexCoord2f(100,-100);
    glVertex3f(100,0,-100);

    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);


    glPushMatrix();
    object1.draw();
    glPopMatrix();

    //globe
    glTranslatef(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2->textureID);
    gluQuadricTexture(quad,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(-90, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(venusRotate, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    drawRandomSpherePoints();

    for (int i=0; i<cityVertices.size()-1; i++)
    {
        vector3f start=cityVertices.at(i);
        vector3f end=cityVertices.at(i+1);
        vector3f perpBisectorDirection=vector3f((start.x+end.x)/2,(start.y+end.y)/2,(start.z+end.z)/2);
        vector3f tan1(perpBisectorDirection.x/10*15,perpBisectorDirection.y/10*15,perpBisectorDirection.z/10*15);
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glLineWidth(12.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

        int t = 30;
        for (int i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
            float pos = (float) i / (float) t;
            GLfloat x = bezierCurve( pos,start.x, tan1.x, end.x);
            GLfloat y = bezierCurve( pos,start.y, tan1.y, end.y);
            // In our case, the z should always be empty
            GLfloat z = bezierCurve(pos,start.z, tan1.z, end.z);

            vector3f result(x, y, z);
            glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        }
        glEnd();

    }
    gluSphere(quad,10,20,20);
    glPopMatrix();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: opengl has a selection mode 'glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);'

Comment: Oh god. Just found this after googling. (http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs553/Handouts/Picking/picking.pdf) Thank you. Would you like to post this as an answer so I can upvote it? (In case you don't reply, I'll post it myself in 24 hours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opengl has a selection mode

> glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);